# Formula for the number of inequivalent k-dimensional complex representations of an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let G be an abelian group, $|G|=n$. Prove that the number of inequivalent k-dimentional complex representions of G  is equal to  the coefficient of $t^k$ in series $(1-t)^{-n}$. Find this coefficient.

I begin. the coefficient of $t^k$ in series $(1-t)^{-n}$ is equal to $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}$.

It is well known facts are
1)any irreducible complex representation of anabelian group G is one-dimensional; 
2)the number of irreducible isomorphism classes of representations of a ﬁnite abelian group equals the order of the group. 
Use Maschke's Theorem.k-dimentional complex representions of G  can be represented as  direct sum  of irreducible  representation. It is a scalar matrix. its elements $a_{ii}$ is an one-dimensional irreducible complex representation of the group G. $a_{ii}$  can take n values. But then the number  k-dimentional complex representions of G  is equal to $n^k.$ And the number of inequivalent k-dimentional complex representions of G  is equal to $\frac{n^k}{k!}.$  I undenstand that I am wrong, because generally speaking this number is not integer generally speaking.

where I am mistaken?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Your mistake is in the final part, in which your counting assumes that any representation is made of *distinct* representations (you can have repeated representations).

Comment: By the way the coefficient of $t^k$ is another one (the exponent of $(1-t)$ is negative), and I think this exercise is intended to be solved without caring of calculating it explicitly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generating function is equal to 
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i.$$
The coefficient of $x^k$ equals, therefore, to the number of ways of writing $k$ as $k=i_1 + i_2 + \dotsc + i_n.$ Now, $i_1$ is the number of copies of the first irrep, $i_2$ the number of copies of the second irrep, etc.

Comment: I don't understand what is irrep (I can not translate this word)

Comment: @nadia-liza: "irrep" is short for "irreducible representation."

Comment: @Stahl thanks for explaining, though I should say that had the OP googled "irrep" it would have been fairly clear what I meant.